# Combined numbers

Tags: mathematics

Lets imagine we have two numbers (positive, whole numbers) $a$ and $b$ ($a>b$).

We know that
$a + b = 999$

and when we *combine* a and b, its scale is exactly $6$

---

**for example:**

$a=888, b=111 $

$ \dfrac{888111}{111888} = 6 $ (false in this case)

find $a$ and $b$

Comment: This is just a math question about solving a system of equations; it doesn't really count as a puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By inspection<sub>jks</sub>:

> $a = 857,\, b = 142$
>  We have $a+b =999,\,1000a + b = 6(1000b + a)$, which is a simple system of two linear equations in two variables, and can be solved uniquely to obtain the above solution.

Answer (score 2):

> a=857, b=142
>
>  Start with $\dfrac{1000a+b}{1000b+a}=6$, giving $5999b=994a$ and substitute $a=999-b$.